# Hi,How to get last 5 days from current date

Tags: sql-server

How to get last 5 days from current date 
below my sqlquery is their please help me Thanks in advance.

```
select b.emp_code,
       b.emp_name,b.GENERAL_SHIFT as g,
       b.FIRST_SHIFT as f, 
       b.SECOND_SHIFT as s, 
       b.THIRD_SHIFT as t,b.dt 
from (
    select a.* from (
      select emp.emp_code,emp.emp_name,
             et.GENERAL_SHIFT, 
             et.FIRST_SHIFT, 
             et.SECOND_SHIFT, 
             et.THIRD_SHIFT,
             --et.day, et.month,et.year,
             convert(DATE,'20'+convert(varchar(10),et.year,120)+'-'+ 
             convert(varchar(10),et.month,120)+'-'+
             convert(varchar(10),et.day,120)) as dt
      from  EMP_FPONM_EMP_TIME_SHEET et, 
            EMP_FPONM_EMPLOYEE_INFORMATION emp
      where et.emp_id = emp.EMP_CODE
      and emp.dept_id = 44
      and EMP.STATUS='Present' 
        and emp.EMP_CODE = 'ONM_001903'
        and emp.SITE_ID=20
      ) as a
      where dt between  getdate()-5 and getdate()
      ) b
```

Comment: This query is not perfect but looks like it returns the correct result. what is wrong with it?

Comment: HERE RESULT IS EMPTY ONLY COLUMNS NAMES RETURNED

Comment: I suggest you start executing from the inner select statement and see in which level you miss the data. I think the where clause et.emp_id = emp.EMP_CODE is not correct. looks like EMP_CODe is a varchar and I guess emp_id is an integer?

Comment: Thank u Emp_id is also varchar now its getting last 5 days but it displayes veritical result but need horizontal  result so how will i get this result please help me

Comment: what change did you made to get the result. I don't understand what you mean of vertical and horizontal. please provide some images to clarify the issue.

Comment: Emp_id Emp_name g f s t dt
Onm_234444 durga 0 2 2 2 2015-02-03
Onm_532465 devi 1 2 2 2 2015-02-04
Onm_654356 ram 0 0 0 0 2015-02-05

Comment: Example:2015-02-03 2015-02-04 2015-02-04 2015-02-05 2015-02-06 i nee like this but same displays vertical how to change horizontal format

Comment: @sahithi You can try [Pivot Table](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/create-pivoted-tables-3-steps) for this problem.

Comment: hi please help how to use pivot table

Answer (score 0):

`DATEADD` will fix your problem :

```
where dt between  DATEADD(day, -5, getdate()) and getdate()
```

Comment: Thank u for ans but i didn't get result iam getting only column names what is mistake their i didnt understood plaese help me

Comment: That means you don't have any valid result in the last 5 days, try to query for a longer period to be sure, 30 days for example. Your problem is solved

Comment: Thanks for your help its getting data now but result displays vertically but  ineed horizontal result

Comment: Example:2015-02-03 2015-02-04 2015-02-04 2015-02-05 2015-02-06 i nee like this but same displays vertical how to change horizontal format

Comment: How will i get last 5 days from our own selected date not system date please suggest me syantax